# Draw a pixel with VGA in long mode

Tags: assembly, operating-system, att, vga

How do I draw a pixel with AT&T assembly in long mode?
I've already enabled VGA mode in the real mode state.

Comment: Don't know what VGA mode you are using, and I assume you know the base address of the video ram. Not sure if it was through VESA or some other means (with VESA compliant modes you can query for the Linear Frame Buffer LFB address). But you simply move a value to the memory address of the pixel you want.If the address of the pixel is in _RDI_ then you can update it with something like `mov    %al,(%rdi)` (use whatever size register as the source containing the data you want.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I'm using mode 0x13

Comment: So mode 0x13 is pretty simple. 320x200 and you can access it through the low memory address at 0xa0000. Each memory location (byte) of mode 0x13 represents a single pixel and contains a 256 bit color. If you want to put blue in the upper left corner pixel you can do `movb $0x20,0xa0000` . If you are in fact in 64-bit  long mode though - I'm assuming in that example you have identity mapped low memory below 1MB. If you have placed video memory elsewhere in virtual address space then replace 0xA0000 with the appropriate memory address.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you, it worked perfectly. Do you perhaps know how to get bigger resolution and maybe a better color system with transparancy?

Comment: If you use VBE you can get higher resolutions, and there are tutorial on OSDEV Wiki you can look through: http://wiki.osdev.org/User:Omarrx024/VESA_Tutorial . If you can't get the resolutions you want through VBE then you would have to write specific device driver code to access the special graphics hardware you have (and that's a non trivial task)

Answer (score 1):

My rep is only 1 so I cant comment but if you'll accept this as a partial answer you should investigate bitplanes. Mode 13 is easy peasy because it all fits in less than 64k at 0xA000 (64000 bytes) but when the graphics mode needs more memory than 64k the VGA adapter employs the overly complicated solution of bitplanes.

A bit plane is a 64k chunk of memory stored on the VGA controllers internal memory which contains at least 4 of these "banks". You need to talk to the VGA controller using the in and out instruction for the relevant ports so as to tell the VGA adaptor which bank you want mapped onto the 0xA000 segment and then you work on the 0xA000 via mov,xor,and, etc as you would with Mode 13.... but.... heres where it gets complicated.

These banks dont just appear as contguous blocks for all Modes. In 16bit and 24bit colour modes, a singly byte in a bank can represent just one of the RGB components and the final output is infact a combination of all the bitplanes overlapping one another like three slides on a projector screen but you can only manipulate one slide at a time having to talk to the VGA controller via IN and OUT instructions to to tell it what bank you want to use.

If memory serves me correct, the VGA controller is a 16 bit bus that needs to be talked to one byte at a time making it even more annoying. Im not sure of the ports but you'll find them on any list thats out there.

Sorry its not a full answer, but a path to investigate. "VGA bitplanes".